# Python How to fill in missing data in a list from data created from a NetCDF file

Tags: python, netcdf

I am trying to write some Python code that reads the Australian Bureau of Meteorology Rain gauge NetCDF files and extracts rainfall for a set of gauges in a catchment. The format is a little strange. They have opted to create a single time step file with every recorded value in it Australia wide for that time step? However when the gauge doesn't record the value and the station are missing. I want to try to find the missing stations and simply create a zero rainfall value. I have identified the Station ID, but how do I add the record of zero to my list?

Here is part of the code:

```
# First LOOP through all files for the day and accumulate data.
for timestep, datafile in enumerate(stationdata):
    print datafile[-16:-3]
    data = netcdf.NetCDFFile(datafile, 'r')
try:
    precip = data.variables['precipitation'].data
except:
    precip = data.variables['precip'].data
try:
    stid = data.variables['station_id'].data
except:
    stid = data.variables['stid'].data
# create np array of indices of the gauge id present in the current file (Note not ALL required ones may be present!!)
idx = np.where(np.in1d(stid, gauge_ids))[0]
print 'index len = '+str(len(idx))+' Gauges: '+str(ngauges)
# This process DOES NOT SEEM to Capture Missing Gauge Data
# If a Gauge ID is not present how to we set its value to Zero for this time step ?
for i in idx:
    print i,stid[i],precip[i], timestep
    timeseries_per_station[str(stid[i])][timestep] = precip[i] # This adds the rainfall to the time series for the Station ID in the found set from its index
data.close()
# Now go through the list of Gauges ngauges with IDs gauge_ids, and fill missing ones with zero
# For stid not in gauge_ids set to Zero ... How ???
# create a Zero list and remove ID's that already have values ??
# Try    [i for i in a if i not in b]
print [k for k in gauge_ids if k not in stid]
for l in [k for k in gauge_ids if k not in stid]:
    print l, timestep
    timeseries_per_station[l][timestep] = 0.0
raw_input('check..')
```

The line `for l in [k for k in gauge_ids if k not in stid]:` identifies the missing station as it is supposed to, but `timeseries_per_station[l][timestep] = -1.0` results in an `IndexError: index out of bounds`. This is where I want to set the missing data to an identifiable value.

It would appear that when the code gets to a data segment with less than the original number of stations (26), and only 25 or 24 etc are read, this error occurs?

Any clues would be most helpful...

The alternative is to use a different structure to read the data into: The structure should be something as follows: For each Time Slice Data file, there is data for Rain Gauge Stations such as, ID, Latitude, Longitude, Precipitation. I want to plot the spatial variation of the Precipitation and the spatial variation for each time slice. The time slice data is contained within the file names of the time slice files.

Thanks

Comment: As hinted by the existing answer, you will get much better responses if you could rewrite the code so that it doesnt rely on your files and data. This is so that people providing answers can copy your code and run it locally.

Comment: It's dangerous to call the file name `data` and also use the attribute `data`.  How about calling incoming file `ncfile`? Then extract variables from `ncfile`, e.g. `precip = ncfile.variables['precip'][:]`.

Answer (score 1):

It's somewhat difficult to see all that is happening here as we don't have the data and your full python script, but as a starting point you could:

- Find the maximum number of observations available at all stations (e.g. `maxN`) and maximum number of stations (`maxS`)
- Create a Numpy array to hold the data you read from file: `mydata=numpy.zeros((maxS,maxN))`
- Start reading data from files and fill in as you are currently doing, but using an index that counts from start to end timestep. If current timestep is not found in file, replace with NaN
  value.

These steps should allow you to end up with an array containing your data that contains missing values where you don't have information. Currently, you are using an array for your data that is the size of the data minus the missing values. You nee to initialize your array with the length of your data plus the missing timesteps. I would also suggest you use `NaN` (`numpy.nan`) values where you don't have information as using zero values will affect the statistics you may want to do on your data. Once you have your data stored properly in an array, you could use the great [Pandas](http://pandas.pydata.org/) library for analyzing your timeseries.

Comment: I think I am creating an Array with all the gauges (if they all occur in the first file ) by using:                                 # initialize data for time series storage
dtypes = zip(gauge_id_list, ['float32']*ngauges)
timeseries_per_station = np.empty((ntimesteps,))
timeseries_per_station.fill(np.nan)
timeseries_per_station = timeseries_per_station.astype(dtypes)                                The problem is, that I need to identify which gauge has missing data, which if more than 1 gauge is tricky  I think ??